# Ruby Scan with regex not finding all patterns

Tags: ruby, regex, substring

I'm trying to use a Regular Expression to find all sub strings in word. It is finding some but not all. On such example is 'an' in the word 'banana'.

```
def substrings str
  pattern = '.'
  subs = []    
  while pattern.length < str.length do
    subs << str.scan(/#{pattern}/)
    pattern << '.'  
  end 
  subs.flatten  
end

puts substrings("banana").sort_by{ |s| "banana".index(/#{s}/)}
```

Comment: What is your question? And, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @sawa I want this to return all substring in the word that is passed in not just some.

Comment: isn't simply `str.scan /#{pattern}/` not yielding an array of matched strings? I don't understand the need for having to manually push each pattern in array.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal I'm pushing because I start wit substring of length 1 and work up to the string length -1

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thats because I put up the list before I understood what you were asking.

Comment: Is the output in my amended answer correct, and do you want it to include "banana"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That looks about right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression matches will never overlap. If you ask for `/../`, you will get `["ba", "na", "na"]`. You will not get `["ba", "an" ...]` because `"an"` overlaps `"ba"`. The next match search will start from the last match's end, always.

If you want to find overlapping sequences, you need to use lookahead/lookbehind to shorten your match size so the matches themselves don't overlap: `/(?=(..))/`. Note that you have to introduce a capture group, since the match itself is an empty string in this case.

Comment: That only matches substrings of a fixed length.

Comment: @sawa: That illustrates a principle that can be applied to the OP's code with minimal changes. I did not think I needed to spell out the solution for you, but here goes: `subs << str.scan(/(?=(#{pattern}))/).flatten`.

Comment: @sawa: I would rather do what you did, without regular expressions, if I wrote it. But this is the minimal modification of OP's code that fixes it, explains the root of the problem, and teaches about an important property of regular expression engines.

Comment: I see: `subs = []; subs << str.scan(/(?=(...))/).flatten
=> [["ban", "ana", "nan", "ana"]]`, repeat for different lengths, and `subs.flatten` at the end. That's nice. @sawa, I think you forgot a pair of braces: `/(?=(.{#{n}}))/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def substrings str
  (0...str.length).flat_map{|i| (i...str.length).map{|j| str[i..j]}}.uniq
end

substrings("banana")
```

Result

```
[
  "b",
  "ba",
  "ban",
  "bana",
  "banan",
  "banana",
  "a",
  "an",
  "ana",
  "anan",
  "anana",
  "n",
  "na",
  "nan",
  "nana"
]
```

or

```
def substrings str
  (0...str.length).to_a.combination(2).map{|r| str[*r]}.uniq
end
```

Result

```
[
  "b",
  "ba",
  "ban",
  "bana",
  "banan",
  "banana",
  "an",
  "ana",
  "anan",
  "anana",
  "nan",
  "nana",
  "na",
  "a"
]
```

Comment: I've thought about that approach before but I would prefer to use a regex

Comment: Then go ahead with your own way.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way that does not use a regex. I see now how it can be done with a regex, but I don't know why you'd want to, unless it's just an exercise.

```
def substrings(str)
  arr = str.chars
  (1..str.size).each_with_object([]) { |i,a|
    a << arr.each_cons(i).to_a.map(&:join) }.flatten
end

substrings("banana")
  #=> ["b", "a", "n", "a", "n", "a", "ba", "an", "na", "an", "na", "ban",
  #    "ana", "nan", "ana", "bana", "anan", "nana", "banan", "anana"]
```

If you want to include the word "banana", change `str.size` to `str.size+1`.

Comment: No, it is not. From OP: "'an' in the word 'banana'" is not in your results either.

Comment: Neither did I. And the question is clear (unless you can't read past the misspelling): "all sub strings in word".